# PHP Class: mysql data as a property

Tags: php, mysql, class

I want to create properties that are set to mysql data.

```
class MyClass{
    private $a = $r['a'];
    private $b = $r['a'];
    private $c = $r['c']; 
}
```

I know this is incorrect syntax but I want you to get the idea.

I could create a method that returns a requested mysql data, but I don't want the function to be called for every single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why reinvent the wheel ?**

check this [mysqli_result::fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get`.

Something like:

```
class MyClass {
  protected $_row = array();

  public function __get( $name )
  {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_row)) {
      return $this->_row[$name];
    }
    return null;
  }

  public function __isset( $name )
  {
    return array_key_exists($name, $this->_row);
  }
}
```

And you could used as:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->load(); // Or any method to load internal data
echo $obj->a . $obj->b;
```

Comment: ajreal has a good point, why are you creating a class with an array to hold the property values and magic getters/settings when mysqli_result::fetch_object (or mysql_fetch_object) can do the same thing without all the legwork?